# R- expand.grid given a data.frame of parameter names and sequence definitions

Tags: r, dataframe, seq

I have a `data.frame` that arbitrarily defines parameter names and sequence boundaries:

```
dfParameterValues <- data.frame(ParameterName = character(), seqFrom = integer(), seqTo = integer(), seqBy = integer())
row1 <- data.frame(ParameterName = "parameterA", seqFrom = 1, seqTo = 2, seqBy = 1)
row2 <- data.frame(ParameterName = "parameterB", seqFrom = 5, seqTo = 7, seqBy = 1)
row3 <- data.frame(ParameterName = "parameterC", seqFrom = 10, seqTo = 11, seqBy = 1)
dfParameterValues <- rbind(dfParameterValues, row1)
dfParameterValues <- rbind(dfParameterValues, row2)
dfParameterValues <- rbind(dfParameterValues, row3)
```

I would like to use this approach to create a grid of c parameter columns based on the number of unique `ParameterName`s that contain r rows of all possible combinations of the sequences given by `seqFrom`, `seqTo`, and `seqBy`. The result would therefore look somewhat like this or should have a content like the following:

```
ParameterA ParameterB ParameterC
1          5          10
1          5          11
1          6          10
1          6          11
1          7          10
1          7          11
2          5          10
2          5          11
2          6          10
2          6          11
2          7          10
2          7          11
```

Edit: Note that the parameter names and their numbers are not known in advance. The data.frame comes from elsewhere so I cannot use the standard static expand.grid approach and need something like a flexible function that creates the expanded grid based on any dataframe with the columns ParameterName, seqFrom, seqTo, seqBy.

I've been playing around with for loops (which is bad to begin with) and it hasn't lead me to any elegant ideas. I can't seem to find a way to come up with the result by using tidyr without constructing the sequences seperately first, either. Do you have any elegant approaches?

Bonus kudos for extending this to include not only numerical sequences, but vectors/sets of characters / other factors, too.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try `paramA <- 1:2; paramB <- 5:7; paramC <- 10:11; expand.grid(paramA, paramB, paramC)`

Comment: Thanks, CPak; maybe I should point out more clearly that the parameter names and their numbers are not known in advance. The data.frame comes from elsewhere so I cannot use a static expand.grid approach. I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: The solution I'm looking for would probably look something along those lines (a very high-level foolish approach here though):
`lapply(originalDataFrame, expand.grid, lapply(???, seq))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off CPak's answer, you could use

```
my_table <- expand.grid(apply(dfParameterValues, 1, function(x) seq(as.numeric(x['seqFrom']), as.numeric(x['seqTo']), as.numeric(x['seqBy']))))
names(my_table) <- c("ParameterA", "ParameterB", "ParameterC")
my_table <- my_table[order(my_table$ParameterA, my_table$ParameterB), ]
```

Comment: Nice! That looks very elegant and works to get the numerical combinations. Is there a way to include the parameter names as column names?

Comment: Thanks! Here's my approach to this in order to be able to use any number of (unknown) parameter names:
`
    grid <- expand.grid(apply(parameterBoundaries, 1, function(x) seq(as.numeric(x['seqFrom']), as.numeric(x['seqTo']), as.numeric(x['seqBy']))))
    colnames(grid) <- parameterBoundaries$ParameterName
`

Answer (score 1):

@smanski's answer is technically correct (and should arguably be accepted since it motivated this), but it is also a good example of when to be careful when using `apply` with `data.frame`s. In this case, the frame contains at least one column that is `character`, so *all* columns are converted, resulting in the need to use `as.numeric`. The safer alternative is to only pull the columns needed, such as either of:

```
expand.grid(apply(dfParameterValues[,-1], 1,
            function(x) seq(x['seqFrom'], x['seqTo'], x['seqBy']) ))
expand.grid(apply(dfParameterValues[,c("seqFrom","seqTo","seqBy")], 1,
            function(x) seq(x['seqFrom'], x['seqTo'], x['seqBy']) ))
```

I prefer the second, because it only pulls what it needs and therefore what it "knows" should be numeric. (I find *explicit* is often safer.)

The reason this is happening is that `apply` silently converts the data to a `matrix`, so to see the effects, try:

```
str(as.matrix(dfParameterValues))
#  chr [1:3, 1:4] "parameterA" "parameterB" "parameterC" " 1" " 5" ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
#   ..$ : chr [1:4] "ParameterName" "seqFrom" "seqTo" "seqBy"
str(as.matrix(dfParameterValues[c("seqFrom","seqTo","seqBy")]))
#  num [1:3, 1:3] 1 5 10 2 7 11 1 1 1
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "2" "3"
#   ..$ : chr [1:3] "seqFrom" "seqTo" "seqBy"
```

(Note the `chr` on the first and the `num` on the second.)

Neither one preserves the parameter names. To do that, just sandwich the call with `setNames`:

```
setNames(
  expand.grid(apply(dfParameterValues[,c("seqFrom","seqTo","seqBy")], 1,
              function(x) seq(x['seqFrom'], x['seqTo'], x['seqBy']) )),
  dfParameterValues$ParameterName)
```

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about the conversion to a matrix. Thanks for the very flexible and elegant solution!